# Visualforce Conditionally Render 2 Different Fields based on 2 conditions

Tags: visualforce, rendered

Calling VF Experts:

Is it possible to conditionally render 2 different fields on a Visualforce page based on a value selected in a picklist?  I have the first condition working properly but unsure if it's possible to add another condition to render a separate field.

Below is the business scenario I am trying to solve for:

1) If Match Partner = "Existing Partner", render a field called "Match Partner Existing" OR 
2) If Match Partner == "New Partner", render a separate field called "Match Partner New"

Code Snippet:

```
<apex:pageblockSection title="Request Details" collapsible="true" columns="1" 
id="pbs1">
   <apex:pageblockSectionItem>
   <apex:outputLabel>Match Partner</apex:outputLabel>
   <apex:actionRegion >
       <apex:inputField value="{!PartnershipRequest__c.MatchPartner__c}" 
   label="Match Partner">
       <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!null}" rerender="op1"/>  
       </apex:inputField>
   </apex:actionRegion>
   </apex:pageblockSectionItem>

    <apex:outputPanel id="op1" >
       <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!If(PartnershipRequest__c.MatchPartner__c 
   == 'Existing Partner',true,false)}" id="op2">
           <apex:pageblockSection>
            <apex:inputField value=" 
    {!PartnershipRequest__c.MatchPartnerExisting__c}"/>
           </apex:pageblockSection>
       </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageblockSection>
```

[image: Render]

Comment: Formatting tip - for code blocks, select the entire region and press Ctrl-K or hit the `{}` button. The entire region must be indented by at least 4 spaces.

Comment: Please note you can *always* repalce `IF(condition, true, false)` with simply `condition`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. You've already got the pattern you need, and the conditions you have in place are entirely independent of one another - so you just need another `<apex:outputPanel>` with a different `rendered` condition.

```
   <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!If(PartnershipRequest__c.MatchPartner__c 
 == 'Existing Partner',true,false)}" id="op2">
```

Side note here: the `rendered` attribute is expecting a Boolean value, and `PartnershipRequest__c.MatchPartner__c == 'Existing Partner'` is already a Boolean expression. You can omit the `IF()` and just do

```
   <apex:outputPanel rendered="{! PartnershipRequest__c.MatchPartner__c 
 == 'Existing Partner' }" id="op2">
```

Your other conditional would be identical save for the text value `'New Partner'`, in a new `<apex:outputPanel>` right after (and outside) this one.

Comment: Thanks @David Reed.  I added the other output panel with seprate condition however the second picklist is still not being rendered separately when the conditions are met (i.e., Match Partner == 'New Partner').   Any ideas?

Comment: Below is the second output panel/condition:      
   `code` <apex:outputPanel id="op3" >
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!PartnershipRequest__c.MatchPartner__c == 
    'New Partner'}" id="op4">
    <apex:pageblockSection >     
    <apex:inputField value="{!PartnershipRequest__c.MatchPartnerNew__c}"/>
    </apex:pageblockSection>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:outputPanel><br/>`code`

Comment: Make sure the `actionSupport` rerender targets that panel too.

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:actionRegion >
<apex:inputField value="{!PartnershipRequest__c.MatchPartner__c}" label="Match 
Partner">
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!null}" rerender="op1,op3"/>  
</apex:inputField>
</apex:actionRegion>
</apex:pageblockSectionItem>

<apex:outputPanel id="op1" >
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!PartnershipRequest__c.MatchPartner__c == 'Existing 
Partner'}" id="op2">
<apex:pageblockSection > 
<apex:inputField value="{!PartnershipRequest__c.MatchPartnerExisting__c}"/>
</apex:pageblockSection>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>

<apex:outputPanel id="op3" >
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!PartnershipRequest__c.MatchPartner__c == 'New 
Partner'}" id="op4">
<apex:pageblockSection >     
<apex:inputField value="{!PartnershipRequest__c.MatchPartnerNew__c}"/>
</apex:pageblockSection>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel><br/>
```